# convert a nodevalue into a string

Tags: php, html, dom

Working on dom html . I want to convert node value to string:

```
 $html = @$dom->loadHTMLFile('url');


  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


  $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');


  $rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

  // loop over the table rows
  foreach ($rows as $text =>$row)
  {
$t=1;

   // get each column by tag name
      $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
//getting values

$rr = @$cols->item(0)->nodeValue;

print $rr; ( it prints values of all 'td' tag fine)
}
print $rr; ( it prints nothing) I want it to print here 

?>
```

I want nodevalues to be converted into string for further manipulation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time and make your question a little bit readable so we could help you better.

Comment: You are suppressing errors with the `@` operator. If an error occurs you will not notice it. E.g. if the document can not be loaded (server down) there would be no node to extract anything. Additionally if you properly indent your code, it would be better readable and much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you loop through the `foreach` you overwrite the value of the `$rr` variable. The second `print $rr` will print the value of the last `td` - if it's empty, then it will print nothing.

If what you are trying to do is print *all* the values, instead write them to an array:

```
$rr = array();
foreach($rows as $text =>$row) {
  $rr[] = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
print_r($rr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  // new dom object
  $dom = new DOMDocument();

  //load the html
  $html = @$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://webapp-da1-01.corp.adobe.com:8300/cfusion/bootstrap/');

  //discard white space
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

  //the table by its tag name
  $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head');

//get all rows from the table
  $la=array();
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

  // loop over the table rows
$array = array();
  foreach ($rows as $text =>$row)
  {
$t=1;
$tt=$text;
   // get each column by tag name
 $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
   // echo the values
      #echo @$cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'';
//      echo @$cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'';
$array[$row] = @$cols->item($t)->nodeValue;
}
print_r ($array);
```

It prints Array
(
)
nothing more. i also used "$cols->item(0)->nodeValue;"

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOM::saveXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) or [DOM::saveHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) to convert node value to string.

Comment: I dont want to save output into a file , I want to save it into a string or a array to manipulate.

Comment: Wish you had clicked on the links I provided, because those 2 functions are **NOT** for saving to any file. Both of these are just returning content into a string.

Answer (score 0):

did you try  @$cols->item(0)->textContent